# __git_ps1 breaks bash's vi mode

Tags: linux, git, bash, ubuntu, ps1

I'm running ubuntu 13.04 and I have a PS1 like this

```
PS1="\$(__git_ps1 '(%s) ')\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ "
```

And I'm used to use the vi mode of bash with `set -o vi`.

However, if `$PWD` is somewhere in the tree in a git root and I press `ESC+/` to search, the indent gets fucked up. With each directory in the tree, it's getting worse.
The results of the search are printed "somewhere", but not where they are supposed to be.

Outside a git root, directly in the git root or without the `$(__git_ps1 '(%s) ')` it works perfectly.

`ESC+k` for is working, no matter where I am.

Here are some examples:

```
(master) flx@t420:~/dev/somegitproject/subdir/subdir$ [press ESC+/]
(master) flx@t420:~/dev/somegitproject/subdir/subdi[type your search here]


(master) flx@t420:~/dev/somegitproject/subdir/subdir/subdir/subdir$ [press ESC+/]
(master) flx@t420:~/dev/somegitproject/subdir/subdir/subdi[type your search here]
```

Everything is fine:

```
(master) flx@t420:~/dev/somegitproject$ [press ESC+/]
(master) flx@t420:~/dev/somegitproject$ /[type your search here]
```

I just noticed, that printing the search results in broken in a git root to:

```
(master) flx@t420:~/dev/somegitproject$ [press ESC+/]
(master) flx@t420:~/dev/somegitproject$ /whateve[enter]
(master) flx@t420:~/dev/somegiwhateve                 tproject$ whatevercommand
```

In a directory without git, it's working as expected:

```
(master) flx@t420:~/dev$ [press ESC+/]
(master) flx@t420:~/dev$ /whateve[enter]
(master) flx@t420:~/dev$ whatevercommand
```

Any idea how to fix this. It's very annoying.

The funny part is, this very same PS1 worked on my old desktop running an old ubuntu installation updated to 13.04. But it is broken in this fresh installation.

Comment: I wonder if this has something to do with the length of the command prompt rather than the GIT branch info itself. I've had similar issues with BASH with extra long command prompts. Your prompt is almost 50 characters long. I use two lines for a command prompt by putting the final `$` on the command line by itself. Not only does it give me more room to type my command, but it solves the command edit issues I use to have. Instead of ending your prompt with `"\$ "`, try `"\n\$ "`.